# A walk through my datas

Tags: regression, descriptive-statistics

I wish to study the effect of a categorical factor on the rate of increase of some parameter Y along a given X explanatory variable.

My data looks like:

```r
# A Walk Through My Data
    
# First, let's (re-)create some data that looks a lot like mine
    
trt <- rep(c("a","b","c","d","e"), each=(9*4))
repet <- rep(rep(c(1,2,3,4), each=9), 5)
    
X <- c(rep(seq(-350, 0, length.out=9), 4), 
    rep(seq(-50, 200, length.out=9), 4), 
    rep(seq(0, 1000, length.out=9), 4), 
    rep(seq(-5, 500, length.out=9), 4), 
    rep(seq(-70, 0, length.out=9), 4))
set.seed(1000)
Y <- c(0.1*X+rnorm(length(X),0,20))
    
mydata <- data.frame(trt=trt, repet=repet, 
    id=paste(trt,":",repet,sep=""), X=X, Y=Y)
    
plot(Y~X,col=as.numeric(as.factor(trt)), 
     pch=as.numeric(as.factor(repet)), data=mydata)
```

We have, thus, 5 treatments (trt) that were each applied to 4 individuals (i.e. 4x5=20 individuals)

individuals were blocked along the "repet" factor (4 levels).

We wish to study the rate of variation of Y along X, between treatments.

My first intuition was: extract the rate of variation from the respective linear model, then compare treatments for the extracted slope, with an anova.

Here we go ...

```r
# linear regression for each "id" and get some statistics about each "id" through regression

intercepts <- c()
    slopes_ci95 <- c()
    trt <- c()
    repet <- c()
    adjRsqs <- c()
    sigmas <- c()
    fstats <- c()
    pval <- c()
    for(idi in sort(unique(mydata$id))){
        
        subdat <- mydata[which(mydata$id==idi),]
  trti <- as.character(subdat$trt[1])
        repeti <- as.character(subdat$repet[1])

        z <- lm(Y~X, data=subdat)
            
        coefs <- as.vector(coef(z))
        ci95_interval <- confint(z)
        ci95s <- coefs-as.vector(ci95_interval[,1])#summary.lm(z)$coefficients[,"Std. Error"]*qt(.975,I(length(subdat[,1])-length(coef(z))))
        
        intercept <- coefs[1]
        slope <- coefs[2]
        intercept_ci95 <- ci95s[1]
        slope_ci95 <- ci95s[2]
        
        intercepts <- c(intercepts, intercept)
        slopes <- c(slopes, slope)
        intercepts_ci95 <- c(intercepts_ci95, intercept_ci95)
        slopes_ci95 <- c(slopes_ci95, slope_ci95)
        
        trt <- c(trt, trti)
        repet <- c(repet, repeti)
        
        adjRsqs <- c(adjRsqs, summary.lm(z)$r.squared)
  sigmas <- c(sigmas, summary.lm(z)$sigma)
        fstats <- c(fstats, summary.lm(z)$fstatistic[[1]])
        pval <- c(pval,anova(z)[5][[1]][1])
        
    }

    regress <- data.frame(
        id=sort(unique(as.character(mydata$id))),
        trt=as.character(trt),
        repet=as.character(repet),
        Intercept=as.numeric(intercepts),
        Slope=as.numeric(slopes),
        AdjRsq=as.numeric(adjRsqs),
        Sigma=as.numeric(sigmas),
        Fstat=as.numeric(fstats),
        Pval=as.numeric(pval),
        CI95_intercept=as.numeric(intercepts_ci95),
        CI95_slope=as.numeric(slopes_ci95)
        )
```

So my "intuition" model would be:

```r
    summary(Mod0 <- lm(Slope ~ repet + trt, data=regress))
```

However we can take the precision of each extracted slope, with "weight" argument passed to lm(), can't we ? So... we have a couple of variables that can, in my opinion, act as proxy for the precision of our "summary-variable", hence act as weights:

```r
summary(Mod1 <- lm(Slope  ~ repet + trt, data=regress, 
    weight=(1/CI95_slope)))

summary(Mod2 <- lm(Slope ~ repet + trt, data=regress, 
    weight=(1/CI95_slope^2)))

summary(Mod3 <- lm(Slope ~ repet + trt, data=regress, 
    weight=AdjRsq))

summary(Mod4 <- lm(Slope ~ repet + trt, data=regress, 
    weight=(1/Pval)))
```

However, I am now lost in the data and can't quite make a decision about the "best" way to analyse this dataset...

My questions are : Is the "summary-variable" a viable approch for analysing these data ? And Do I do it well ? What weights should I choose, if any ? and is there some better way to do it all ?